# Необратимое шифрование с уникальным результатом

Tags: криптография, шифрование, md5

Подскажите, как решить вот такую задачку. Есть id пользователя, типа 1234567890, нужно зашифровать его так, чтобы его нельзя было расшифровать обратно, но он остался уникальным. То есть мне нужна возможность посчитать уникальных пользователей, но не иметь возможности узнать их настоящие id.

Я склоняюсь к `md5(id).str(0,24)`;

Comment: а зачем .str(0,24) ?

Comment: Если функция шифрования известна, а id пользователей - это просто числа, то какой бы хитрой не была функция, всегда можно будет запустить обычный цикл, сгенерировать всё и дешифровать. Причем, думаю, это можно будет сделать за пару часов на любом компе. (Я исхожу из того, что пользователей вряд ли будет большее 10^9, а функция генерации не очень долгая - иначе применять ее на нагруженных проектах не стоит.)

Comment: Cогласен с @KoVadim, очень странная задача посчитать количество уникальных, используя реальные ID, но при этом счет вести по хэшу.
Если нужно сделать уникальными, то добавь к хешу, например, микросекунды.
Попробуй пояснить основную суть проблемы.

Comment: Пришла в голову идея, как это можно сделать, - просто нужно дергать random на каждый вывод id. Правда придется обеспечить уникальность (например, большим хешем, который хранит использованные id). Но в этом случае будет действительно очень сложно узнать реальный id (если только Вы не добавите какую-то другую уникальную информацию). Для пущей надежности, новые id можно перемешать или даже просто отсортировать.

Comment: @eicto, чтоб не расшифровали.

Суть проблемы в том, что я хочу считать пользователей, но так, чтобы их нельзя было однозначно идентифицировать. random не подходит, он нарушает уникальность. Скорее, требуются функции хеширования (вполне себе тяжелого) с отрезанием некоторой части результата. Что позволит оставить уникальность и скрыть реальный идентификатор. Задумываясь об md5, я считаю, что в варианте md5(id).str(0,24) она не подходит, так как позволяет быстро просчитать возможные результаты, которых будет совсем не много. Возможно, Вам известна более подходящая функция?

Comment: При правильном подходе random не нарушит уникальность. Но больше таких функций в принципе быть не может. Почитайте внимательно мой первый комментарий.

Comment: @KoVadim, покажите мне правильный подход с random, я хочу его видеть. Ну, я все же рассчитываю на хитрую функцию с потерей данных. Хотя, да, понимаю, что возможности ограничены. Блин, пришла гениальная идея в виде RSA, но и оно не поможет. Пожалуй, здесь может быть только наркоманский алгоритм... в общем, да, в текущем варианте задачу не решить.

Comment: А в чем то проблема? в цикле получаем очередного пользователя,rand получаем случайное число. Проверяем, не использовали ли это число раньше. Если использовали, то либо дергаем ещё раз rand, или просто добавляем 1 (или другое удобное число - 3,5) до тех пор, пока не получится уникальное. Выводим полученный id и запись. Полученный id заносим в хэш/массив для дальнейших проверок.

Все.

Удобное число - это такое, чтобы если его добавлять, равномерно размазывало по всему диапазону. 2 не подходит, так как она будет выделять только четные или только нечетные числа. (Да, если вышли за пределы - mod.

Comment: А просто номер по порядку в качестве уникального ID не подойдет?

Comment: @mikelsv, т.е. у вас есть список пользователей и есть их сообщения в недоверенном месте, вам хочется, чтобы пользователи постили сообщения под уникальным id, который нельзя сопоставить с тем, что у вас в базе. Т.е. худщий вариант - наркоманы-террористы постят из вашего месенджера, а потом вас накрывает ЦСБ, вам пофиг, что постили через вас, но террористических наркоманов сдавать не хочется (в смысле кто что постил - не узнать)? 

Все верно?

Comment: Мне кажется, без того, чтобы хранить соль на клиенте, не обойтись.

Comment: http://ideone.com/NgEJTE

Answer (score 2):

Решается задача обычно так:

1. Генерируем т.н. [соль/salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) - случайный набор символов, соль обычно одна и та же для всех наборов.
2. Проводим конкатенацию id юзера и соли.
3. Вычисляем хэш (берем более-менее любой алгоритм), пусть это будет MD5, хотя я бы рекомендовал SHA-256 или Whirlpool - MD5 уже давно считается слабым хэш алгоритмом.

Итоговый алгоритм будет примерно такой: `hash(id+salt)`, некоторые извращенцы любят измываться и так: `hash(hash(id+salt1)+salt2)` - ну и т.д. - насколько позволит фантазия.

В таком разрезе вероятность взлома хэша простым перебором или [радужными таблицами](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%E0%E4%F3%E6%ED%E0%FF_%F2%E0%E1%EB%E8%F6%E0) резко (на порядки) снижается.

Comment: Когда известна соль и диапазон id, посчитать хеши и найти нужный довольно просто. А всякие извращения всего лишь немного замедлят этот процесс.

Comment: @mikelsv, если у вас злоумышленник изначально примерно знает ваш секрет (точнее - гарантированно знает диапазон), то как вы вообще собрались его защитить?

Comment: В дополнение к ответу: также можно использовать алгоритмы `Blowfish`/`HAVAL`/`Snefru`.  
Кстати, пришла в голову идея: берём строку с id, разделяем её пополам. Первую половину шифруем в `Whirlpool`, а вторую, например в `HAVAL`, и склеиваем результат в одну строку. Как раз тут и будет уникальность.

Comment: Какова вероятность коллизии у MD5? 

Напр., на диапазоне id 0..1E9 при простом `md5(id)` сколько получится одинаковых первых 24 из 32 шестнадцатиричных знаков хэша?